# What do availableVolume and availableVolumeBase mean on etherdelta.com?

Tags: blockchain, etherdelta

Etherdelta API allows to see existing orders.
There are some fields in the order the meaning of which I don't understand. Could anyone explain me such fields as availableVolume, ethAvailableVolume, availableVolumeBase, ethAvailableVolumeBase, amountFilled? Do these fields changed in time? If yes, how does it happend?

Etherdelta API doc: https://github.com/etherdelta/etherdelta.github.io/blob/master/docs/API.md

```
{
  "id": "4e17ce3e16b0ab215c8224245c91f5bd6fbcb8e99a5612dc787f2d200a6673d4_sell",
  "amount": "-8.1803308489365e+22",
  "price": "0.000007697",
  "tokenGet": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  "amountGet": "629640065442642300",
  "tokenGive": "0xd96b9fd7586d9ea24c950d24399be4fb65372fdd",
  "amountGive": "8.1803308489365e+22",
  "expires": "4820340",
  "nonce": "33307137838216790",
  "v": 28,
  "r": "0xe0e1e1451ca72d5d8c948edba25f931c99570bac7c0a111b595dd480c69690c1",
  "s": "0x56ce5c279b658e738467c83b33b841b6738ff68c6282de3c1850c2f87db2ef38",
  "user": "0x38FcE8aa65Ea74219BD2c07A882570B96DfE6a40",
  "updated": "2017-12-29T21:10:31.441Z",
  "availableVolume": "8.180330848936498635832142393140184487462648e+22",
  "ethAvailableVolume": "81803.30848936498",
  "availableVolumeBase": "629640065442642300",
  "ethAvailableVolumeBase": "0.6296400654426423",
  "amountFilled": null
}
```

Answer (score 1):

- `amountGet`: total how much of the token the seller wants
- `availableVolumeBase`: how much of the token the seller wants is available to fill
- `amountFilled`: how much of the token the seller wants has been filled

The fields do change over time